# Laravel checkbox checked issue

Tags: html, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am using form model binding and I have a check box field in my edit form.

```
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
                {!! Form::checkbox('is_played', 1, $game->is_played === 1 ? true : false, ['id' => 'is-game-played-check', 'class' => 'form-check-input', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) !!}
                <input type="hidden" name="is_played" value="0">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="is-game-played-check">
                    IS played ?
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I come to my edit view, every other field in the form gets populated without any problem but checkbox does not get checked when the condition `$game->is_played === 1` is ensured. I also noticed that when I refresh the page checkbox get checked if the condition `$game->is_played === 1` is ensured.

I also tried using HTML instead of Laravel's form helpers and again it worked without any problem.

```
<input id="is-game-played-check" class="form-check-input" {{ $game->is_played === 1 ? 'checked' : '' }} name="is_played" type="checkbox"value="1">
```

What can be the issue here ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: When you check the question i used `===` in HTML too and it worked. I do not think the problem is related to that.

Answer (score 0):

`$a === $b` returns `true` if `$a` is equal to `$b` and they are of the same type.
in this case `$game->is_played === 1` returns false because `$game->is_played` is not type of integer as `1`

So the solution is to use `==` instead of `===`

Comment: I tried that before I asked that question. The result was the same. And is_played field is an integer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input id="is-game-played-check" class="form-check-input" {{ ($game->is_played === 1) ? 'checked' : '' }} name="is_played" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Just add `()`.

Comment: If you read the question, the raw HTML version is already working. the problem occurs when I create the checkbox via Laravel's form helper.

Comment: Do you really need to use the laravel's form builder? If not, just use the html-typed.

Comment: If so, try replace this `Form::checkbox('is_played'` to this `Form::checkbox(' checked'`